# Creating a stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, matrix, bar-chart, visualization, stacked-chart

I have a matrix with 10 rows and 2 columns, I want to create a bar chart which is stacked by rows but it is getting stacked by columns.
This is my code for the matrix

```
population_matrix<-matrix(c(filter_data$Rural.population,
                           filter_data$Urban.population),
                           nrow = 10,ncol = 2,byrow = FALSE)
```

And, this the code for bar chart

```
barplot(population_matrix/1000000,
         xlab = "States",ylab = "Population (in Millions)",
         col = c("Green","Blue"),
         main = "Statewise population",
         border = "Black")
```

I wanted columns rural population and urban population to be stacked for each state differentiated by colors. Instead rural population got stacked in one column while urban population got stacked in another.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of data using `dput()` as this will allow other people to run your code and see what the data looks like? It's difficult to help without seeing the data.

Comment: try transposing the matrix with `t` - i.e., `barplot(t(population_matrix)/1000000, ...` - though without your data or desired output its difficult to tell

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have data like this

```
#    country rural urban
# 1        A    17    34
# 2        B    48    39
# 3        C    40    12
# ...
```

and can directly do:

```
barplot(t(dat[2:3]),  ## or `dat[c('rural', 'urban')]`
        xlab="States", ylab="Population (in Millions)",
        col=3:4,
        main="Statewise population",
        border="Black",
        names.arg=dat$country,
        legend.text=c('rural', 'urban'))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J"), rural = c(46, 47, 20, 43, 35, 30, 39, 14, 36, 
38), urban = c(27, 38, 47, 19, 27, 47, 49, 13, 28, 32)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```